# NavigationBar Appearance and Background Image

Tags: ios, image, uinavigationbar, background-image, tintcolor

The code below is where I have been setting the navigationbar appearance tintcolor. How would I add a background image instead?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:
                           [UIColor colorWithRed:0.158 green:0.457 blue:0.405 alpha:1]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [-setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationBar/setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:) method. It is the simplest way to do this.
For example:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarBackground"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```